# SQL Insert rows from two corresponding comma delimited sets of strings

Tags: sql, database, insert

I would like to take two separate strings of value pairs delimited by commas and insert each pair into a row in the database.

For example:

```
X = "1,2,3"     Y = "A,B,C"    =>     X  |  Y   
                                     ---------             
                                      1  |  A
                                      2  |  B
                                      3  |  C
```

I am using MSSQL 2008, but solutions for any database would be greatly appreciated. Also if there is a better method to handle inserting these sets of data other than just writing a SQL query please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server parse the lists using a method like this: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html. Tried and true, works great.

Answer (score 0):

Sam

```
INSERT INTO foo (X,Y) VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C');
```

In response to:

> Also if there is a better method to handle inserting these sets of data other than just writing a SQL query please explain in detail.

There is no way to insert data into a SQL database other than a SQL query.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about parameterizing that and passing it to a stored procedure?